# Overwrite Spring HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring

Code Repo: https://github.com/kenuiuc/springboot-demo

I have an endpoint comsuming data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format
If I send a PUT request like this:

```
curl --request PUT \
  --url http://localhost:18080/user \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' \
  --data name=ken%
```

As you can see the data `name=ken%` is in illegal URL format so I get 500 response and the server-side error log:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-05-27T02:25:36.849+00:00",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "path": "/user"
}
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern
    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:187) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.read(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:356) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.parseIfNecessary(FormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:88) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.0-20210520.224402-561.jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_291]
```

My goal is to let it return 400 status instead of 500 since this error is actually the client's fault not my server's fault

So I extended the `org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter` and overrided the `read()` method

```
public class CustomizedFormHttpMsgConverter extends FormHttpMessageConverter {
    @Override
    public MultiValueMap<String, String> read(@Nullable Class<? extends MultiValueMap<String, ?>> clazz,
            HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {

        MediaType contentType = inputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType();
        Charset charset = (contentType != null && contentType.getCharset() != null ?
                contentType.getCharset() : StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String body = StreamUtils.copyToString(inputMessage.getBody(), charset);

        String[] pairs = StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(body, "&");
        MultiValueMap<String, String> result = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(pairs.length);
        for (String pair : pairs) {
            int idx = pair.indexOf('=');
            if (idx == -1) {
                result.add(URLDecoder.decode(pair, charset.name()), null);
            }
            else {
                try {
                    String name = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), charset.name());
                    String value = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), charset.name());
                    result.add(name, value);
                } catch (Throwable th) {
                    System.out.println("HI KEN I GOT HERE!");
                    throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException(th.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then I registered this customized converter in my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class CoreConfig {
    @Bean("customizedFormHttpMsgConverter")
    public FormHttpMessageConverter createMyConverter() {
        return new CustomizedFormHttpMsgConverter();
    }
}
```

Now I can see my converter is successfully registered through my debug endpoint (/myConfig):

```
{
  "requestMappingHandlerAdapter-converters": [
    "com.ken.demo.CustomizedFormHttpMsgConverter@576c5536",
    "org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter@45d20f3d",
    "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@55ecbafe",
    "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@3b567dad",
    "org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter@60ecdde8",
    "org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceRegionHttpMessageConverter@54fac191",
    "org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter@10497d4",
    "org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter@9b7294c",
    "org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@5a8ba37c",
    "org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@f32a60f",
    "org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter@dc61831"
  ],
  "configurers": [
    "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter@257cc1fc",
    "org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration$MetricsWebMvcConfigurer@42e22a53"
  ],
  "converters": [
    "com.ken.demo.CustomizedFormHttpMsgConverter@576c5536",
    "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@55ecbafe",
    "org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@5a8ba37c"
  ]
}
```

However, it looks like the CustomizedFormHttpMsgConverter is never used because the illegal request will still result in the same error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern
    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:187) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.read(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:356) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
```

Of course, my debug msg `"HI KEN I GOT THERE"` is never printed out

My questions are:

1. Why my registered CustomizedFormHttpMsgConverter never get used?
2. Is my approach (to extend FormHttpMessageConverter) the right way of doing things?

Again my goal is just to change the 500 response to 400 upon URL decoding failures

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the FormHttpMessageConverter is called by filter chain. I have not tested yet but the suggestion is that you should write your own filter and calling your custom converter for this case.

How to define a filter and register it: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing so much for just a invalidArgumentException that also for a specific use-case (Param validation).

Put a single Handler for any/all invalidArgumentException thrown from controller.
Now, even if spring or your code throw this exception, you will return custom message and status as you needed.

Sample code :

```
@ExceptionHandler (value = {IllegalArgumentException.class})
public final ResponseEntity<ServiceErrorResponse> invalidInputs(Exception e) {
    
    // preparing the response body as per the template
    // assigns exception message thrown by the failed method or class 
    // to the service response and sets respective HTTP status, code
            
    return new ResponseEntity<ServiceErrorResponse>(e.getMessage(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```